# StaleObjectStateException while trying to lock domain object

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I've recently come across some concurrent modification errors while trying to add child objects to a list on a parent object.

From what I've read, adding the child objects will bump the version number on the parent object, and so if another thread is midway through my create method it'll complain.

Fair enough.

I went back and tried to lock the domain object so it will block until the previous addition is complete. Surprisingly, it now seems to throw a StaleObjectStateException when I try and lock the object!

Here's my test code:

```
  def create(User user, Company company, ReferenceCodeCommand cmd) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      log.debug("superbooking type: " + cmd.superBooking.getClass().getName())                                                                                                                          
      cmd.superBooking.refresh();      
      log.debug("#" + random + " Locking superbooking: " + superBooking.id)                                                                                                                                                                  
      def superBooking = SuperBooking.lock(cmd.superBooking.id)  
      log.debug("#" + random + " Superbooking: " + superBooking.id + " locked")                                                                                                                                         
      def referenceCode = new ReferenceCode(cmd.properties)                                                                                                                                             

      def random = Math.random()                                                                                                                                                                        

      log.debug("#" + random + " ReferenceCode test point 1. SuperBooking version " + referenceCode.superBooking.version)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
      superBooking.addToRefs(referenceCode)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
      log.debug("#" + random + " ReferenceCode test point 2. SuperBooking version " + superBooking.version)                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

      if (!referenceCode.hasErrors()                                                                                                                                                                    
              && referenceCode.save(flush: true)) {                                                                                                                                                     
          log.debug("ReferenceCode saved successfully")                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
      } else {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
          log.warn("#" + random + " ReferenceCode not saved successfully ${referenceCode}.")                                                                                                            
      }                                                                                                                                                                                                 
      log.debug("#" + random + " ReferenceCode test point 3. SuperBooking version " + superBooking.version)                                                                                             
      superBooking.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)                                                                                                                                                 
      log.debug("#" + random + " ReferenceCode test point 4. SuperBooking version " + superBooking.version)                                                                                             

      return referenceCode                                                                                                                                                                              
  }
```

And here's some sample output:

```
2013-09-06 13:31:21,645 [http-bio-8080-exec-19] DEBUG dao.ReferenceCodeDAOService  - superbooking type: com.ngs.id.model.SuperBooking
2013-09-06 13:31:21,667 [http-bio-8080-exec-19] DEBUG dao.ReferenceCodeDAOService  - #0.06947409938388194 Locking superbooking: 208535
2013-09-06 13:31:21,667 [http-bio-8080-exec-19] DEBUG dao.ReferenceCodeDAOService  - #0.06947409938388194 Superbooking: 208535 locked
2013-09-06 13:31:21,667 [http-bio-8080-exec-19] DEBUG dao.ReferenceCodeDAOService  - #0.06947409938388194 ReferenceCode test point 1. SuperBooking version 6
2013-09-06 13:31:21,667 [http-bio-8080-exec-19] DEBUG dao.ReferenceCodeDAOService  - #0.06947409938388194 ReferenceCode test point 2. SuperBooking version 6
2013-09-06 13:31:21,701 [http-bio-8080-exec-19] DEBUG dao.ReferenceCodeDAOService  - #0.06947409938388194 ReferenceCode test point 3. SuperBooking version 7
2013-09-06 13:31:21,708 [http-bio-8080-exec-19] DEBUG dao.ReferenceCodeDAOService  - #0.06947409938388194 ReferenceCode test point 4. SuperBooking version 7
| Error 2013-09-06 13:31:21,715 [http-bio-8080-exec-20] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - StaleObjectStateException occurred when processing request: [POST] /interpreter-direct/api/superBooking/208535/referenceCode/
Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [com.ngs.id.model.SuperBooking#208535]. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [com.ngs.id.model.SuperBooking#208535]
```

The error happens on the line where I'm locking the SuperBooking. This is really confusing to me: from what I've read, lock() will fetch the row from the DB and lock it until the transaction is complete. I would have thought that a StaleObjectStateException doesn't even make sense here.

Does anyone have any tips for me, or perhaps an alternate approach? This has a serious impact on our application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use the db locking in order to support multi-servers that can use the same db.
It looks like you code is fine. What can cause this exception is having run on debug and stop without proper finish the execution, therefore the db transaction is not committed and the lock remains.
Try to execute this when no transaction is open for the same cmd.superBooking.id. Or try to use different ids when testing.
In general, if it is more likely that your application will not perform several update on the same row,  use optimistic locking instead. I.e. Instead of using lock method use try and catch for StaleObjectException.

Comment: Thanks Tal, unfortunately I know that often the javascript front end will send updates in bursts, which consistently leads to concurrency issues. When I first started on this problem transactions were off, so that didn't help.